# geom_vline + geom_text: align labels when labels are rotated vertically

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting with `ggplot` and putting some vertical labels on to the x-intercepts as below:

```
d=data.frame(date=as.Date(c("1971-09-01", "1991-12-01", "1994-12-01", "2000-01-01", "2002-08-01")),
             event=c(2.6, 14.1, 30.3, 60.5, 91.3))
ggplot() +
  scale_x_date(limits=as.Date(c("1970-1-1", "2010-12-31"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="", breaks=NULL, limits=c(0,1)) +
  geom_vline(data=d, mapping=aes(xintercept=date), color="blue") +
  geom_text(data=d, mapping=aes(x=date, y=0, label=event), 
            size=4, angle=270, vjust=-0.4, hjust=7)
```

My chart is like this:

[image]

How do I align the number `2.6` on the first x-intercept to be the same as the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrong angle, for horizontal (90 degrees rotation)

```
  geom_text(data=d, mapping=aes(x=date, y=0, label=event), 
        size=4, angle=90, vjust=-1, hjust=-1.1)
```

or for vertical on the other side (270 degrees rotation)

```
  geom_text(data=d, mapping=aes(x=date, y=0, label=event), 
        size=4, angle=270, vjust=-1, hjust=1.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set the *y* in the middle (0.5 instead of 0) and do not use *hjust*:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = date, y = 0.5, label = event)) +
  geom_text(size = 4, angle = 270, vjust = -0.7) +
  geom_vline(mapping = aes(xintercept = date), color = "blue") +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("1970-1-1", "2010-12-31"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks = NULL, limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image]